# Message in the chat after clicking the adaptive card

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

is there any way to show the message from the user side once the adaptive card is clicked? The bot can be accessed through webchat.

For example, if I click on the first attachment in the below pic, I need to get an message from the user side(in this case "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq").

[image]

I know that I can use hero cards, but the problem with them is that they cannot wrap the text. I also know that we can suggested actions, but we want the options in a vertical fashion.

I'm attaching the work that I have done below.

[image]

Here text is a string and value is an object.

Comment: Can you update your question to include which client your bot will be accessed thru (Web Chat, Facebook, Teams, etc.)? Whether or not this is possible depends entirely on the client your customers will be using. It is not possible from the bot. If your customers are using [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), then absolutely this is possible. Any other client and it will depend on the available features of that client.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Hi thanks for the reply, I've updated the question. Yes, we are using web chat

Answer (score 0):

Directway is not possbile you have to write the customprompt to handle this . Refer the article how to implement this feature

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/solution-adaptive-card-event-implementation-using-waterfalldialog-bot-framewor/

Comment: Hi @Vinoth Rajendran, thanks for the reply, instead of displaying the message from the bot side, can we display that message from the user side? The article shows the former.